# Is it safe to upgrade to MySQL 5.5?

Tags: innodb, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am running a number of Joomla 2.5 sites with a large number of extension, plugins and modules on a VPS server. The server environment is as follows:

CENTOS 5.8 x86_64
WHM 11.32.5 (build 11)
Apache version: 2.2.23
PHP version: 5.3.17
5.1.65-cll
Joomla: 2.5.7

I would like to upgrade MySQL to version 5.5. As I understand it, MySQL has changed the default engine from MyISAM to INNOdb, which is now a requirement for Joomla 3.0. My questions are the following:

1. Will I risk my site/database integrity of my existing Joomla 2.5 sites by upgrading MySQL to 5.5?
2. Will my existing databases remain in MyISAM format or will they be converted to INNOdb in the process?
3. I have read a lot of posts of people complaining about large and growomh file sizes of /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 after upgrading, does this in fact pose a problem?
4. Will my query execution time of my existing sites be negatively affected?
5. Bottomline: is it advisable to upgrade MySQL in my scenario?

I thank you all for you help and input.

Comment: By the way it has only changes it's default engine, it's still supporting MyISAM.

Answer (score 2):

1. As far as I know and is mentioned in [Joomla Technical Requirements](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html), there won't be any problems cause Joomla is compatible with MySQL 5.0.4 and above
2. Joomla 2.5 is using InnoDB by default. At least my websites are!
3. No idea! but I'm using Joomla 2.5 with MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu and I haven't faced any annoying problems.
4. MySQL 5.5 has gained more performance than it's older version so I don't think you may face any performance issues. [(This may help)](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/five-reasons-to-upgrade-to-mysql-5-5-2010-12-15/)
5. I would recommend you to test your website in test environment similar to your production environment with these new technologies (You can use virtual machines for example). There are too many useful applications out there that can help you by creating fake visitors and analyzing performance. So you can compare your new setup with the old one and you can test if there are any incompatibility issues with your new setup.

I hope my answer was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3 requires Innodb whereas 2.5 used whatever the default was in your installation which for most people is Innodb.